# Problems with primary group (gid), secondary group and permissions

Tags: permissions, users, nfs, group

I hope my question is not repeated, as I have been searching the Internet for several days with different keywords and I can't find the solution to my problem with the permissions.

I have a shared folder set up on a server. The options for this folder are:

```
user2@server:~$ mount
Y.Y.Y.Y:/Data on /media/Data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=X.X.X.X,local_lock=none,addr=Y.Y.Y.Y)
```

"user2" is the user I want to access the folder using the group "wholegroup".
In the first part I get permission denied. It is normal because "user2" is not the owner, he is not in the group to which the folder belongs and the folder has neither r nor x permissions for any user:

```
user2@server:~$ id
uid=1001(user2) gid=1001(user2) groups=1001(user2)
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/Data/
ls: cannot open directory '/media/Data/': Permission denied
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/
total 5
drwxr-x--- 6 user1  wholegroup      6 Aug 15 22:59 Data
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           4096 May 15 16:12 OtherData
user2@server:~$
```

Now from "user1" with admin permissions, I add "user2" to the group "wholegroup":

```
user1@server:~$ sudo usermod -a -G wholegroup user2
```

I log out and log in to make "user2" changes effective:

```
user2@server:~$ exit
logout
Connection to X.X.X.X closed.
user1@computer:~$ ssh user2@X.X.X.X
```

I check the groups of "user2" and try to access the folder:

```
user2@server:~$ id
uid=1001(user2) gid=1001(user2) groups=1001(user2),166636(wholegroup)
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/Data/
ls: cannot open directory '/media/Data/': Permission denied
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/
total 5
drwxr-x--- 6 user1 wholegroup    6 Aug 15 22:59 Data
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        4096 May 15 16:12 OtherData
user2@server:~$
```

It tells me that I do not have permissions. This is what I don't understand, if "user2" belongs to "wholegroup" as a secondary group and the folder has r and x permissions for the group, why can't I access it? Does it have to be the primary group "wholegroup" to access?

I do the test by changing the group to primary:

```
user1@server:~$ sudo usermod -g wholegroup user2



user2@server:~$ exit
logout
Connection to X.X.X.X closed.
user1@computer:~$ ssh user2@X.X.X.X
user2@server:~$ id
uid=1001(user2) gid=166636(wholegroup) groups=166636(wholegroup)
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/Data/
total 34
drwxr-x--- 23 user1 wholegroup 25 Sep  7 11:58 Data
drwxr-x---  5 user1 wholegroup  5 Aug 17 13:02 Music
drwxr-x---  6 user1 wholegroup  6 Aug 15 22:59 Video
user2@server:~$ ls -l /media/
total 5
drwxr-x--- 6 user1 wholegroup    6 Aug 15 22:59 Data
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        4096 May 15 16:12 OtherData
user2@server:~$
```

Could you explain me why it does not work as a secondary group, what am I doing wrong and what is the solution? Should I use some special permission like SUID or GUID?

Thanks so much!

Comment: There's an answer in this Q/A which might be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206062/nfs-permission-problem-with-secondary-groups

Comment: @A.B ok, I will delete the other one, if I see that I don't get an answer in this one, I will delete this post and open it in the first one. The truth is that I am quite desperate, I don't usually ask around here and I have read many pages and forums but none of them help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution thanks to [super_ik's](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/17dx4w4/comment/k60goju/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [Dolapevich's](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/17dx4w4/comment/k60nhgf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) comments on Reddit.

The failure was that I had not created the user in the server. The solution in my specific case was to create `user2` and add it to the group `wholegroup` which was already created previously on the server.

I quote from super_ik's comment:

> If I recall correctly the access checking is performed on the server side and the server only receives the uid and gid of the process accessing the folder. If the server does not know these UIDs it also can’t lookup their secondary groups.